# How to: Javascript get file name on click without path and insert it into a new image link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, filenames

The idea is the visitor clicks on a thumbnail and a modal opens with the bigger image. I am trying to get the file name onClick (when the visitor clicks on the image) and then I would like to insert it into a link of the now open modal to show the bigger image. So far I just have created a modal for every image, but this is getting ridiculous long.

This is what I tried now so far:

This is the image with the  tag to open the modal. The image is in the thumbnail folder and I would like to save the name inst01.jpg into a variable.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal"><img class="img-fluid" src="/images/thumbs/inst01.jpg" onclick="getName()"></a>
```

This is the modal. The original image is in the gallery folder and I would like to insert the saved file name inst01.jpg into the link to open the original image:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="imageModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Image 1</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <img src="images/gallery/inst01sm.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to google for a javascript function and I came up with this one:

```
function getName() {
     var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
     var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
     // or, try this, 
     // var filename = fullPath.split("/").pop();

    document.getElementById("result").value = filename;
 }
```

But I have no idea where I have to create the filename variable, nor do I know how to create function which would insert the filename into another link when the modal opens.

I hope it is clear what I want to do.
Thanks for reading so far and helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow what you're trying to do, but I gave it a shot. I renamed `getName` to `setModalImageSrc` and changed it to take the current image as a parameter. I pull out just the image name (ignoring the rest of the path) and use it to set the modal image source using the pattern `/images/gallery/${clickedImageName}sm.jpg`. If that's not quite right, let me know where my assumptions are wrong and I'll adjust.

```js
function setModalImageSrc(img) {
  const fullPath = img.src;
  const imageName = fullPath.match(/\w+(?=\.jpg$)/)[0];
  document.getElementById("imgModal").src = `/images/gallery/${imageName}sm.jpg`
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal"><img class="img-fluid" src="/images/thumbs/inst01.jpg" onclick="setModalImageSrc(this)"></a> 

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="imageModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Image 1</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <img id="imgModal" src="/images/gallery/inst01sm.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No this is sadly not working, although I guess you understood what I am trying to accomplish. The modal just shows nothing now. No image at all (not even a broken image link).

Comment: I just noticed that the modal image src should be `/images` instead of `images`

Comment: I am not editing this above. It is working now. I was typing the code to learn and misspelled something. It works now. Thanks so much. Could you explain in a sentence how this is working. I know myself around html and css, but have never deep dived into javascript. As far as I understand the function is triggered when image is clicked, right? But why is the id (imgModal) all that is needed to create or load the new src link?

Comment: The onclick event is invoked with `setModalImageSrc(this)` where `this` is the current image, which is passed in as the `img` parameter. We figure out what the image name is and then use a predetermined pattern to map that to a gallery image. Make sense?

Comment: I understand the script (except for the pattern, but that's ok). What I don't understand why I can embed the script right before the closing body tag and still the onClick on the image works. I believed that since the browser goes through the html code from top to bottom, that it would try to interpret the onClick event before even knowing that a script file exists.

Comment: Handlers (and functions in general) are only evaluated when they are invoked, i.e. not when the page loads - here's a simple example to try in the console - `f = () => x;` `f();` (error) `x = 1;` `f();`